# Crafting Custom mob's spawn egg in minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft

So I'm trying to make a crafting recipe for the spawn egg assigned to my custom mob. Is there a way to do this?

We can make crafting recipe for default mobs for example this one:

```
{
  "format_version": "1.12",
  "minecraft:recipe_shaped": {
    "description": {
    "identifier": "minecraft:bat_spawn_egg"
    },


    "tags": [ "crafting_table" ],
    "pattern": [
      "   ",
      "#-#",
      "   "
    ],
    "key": {
      "#": {
        "item": "minecraft:feather"
      },
      "-": {
        "item": "minecraft:diamond"
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "item": "minecraft:spawn_egg",
      "data": 19
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this for custom mob's spawn egg?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

In the "result" section, you should simply add the following:

```
"item": "minecraft:spawn_egg",
"data": "query.get_actor_info_id('yourNamespace:yourEntity')"
```